# Plotting data point statistics (min,max,median)

Tags: gnuplot

My file (`file.dat`) contains the following format

```
#X    Avg       Median  Min         Max
6144  329.355   329.368 329.058899  329.504681
7168  447.697   447.717 447.254499  447.886343
8192  582.577   582.611 581.954116  582.844339
9216  739.178   739.211 738.535311  739.525144
10240  911.311  911.406 910.030310  911.942631
11264  1103.01  1103.08 1101.368124 1103.849248
12288  1312.4   1312.54 1310.437674 1313.122151
```

How could I plot the `Median` as a data point and then `Min` and `Max` as the errors with `candlesticks`, `errorb` or similar showing the intervals?

[image]

I have done the following

```
plot "file.dat" u 1:3:4:5 w yerrorbars pt 3 lc rgb 'red'
```

But the output graph is not perceptible. Any other ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should re-think the way of displaying your data.
How should a deviation of less than 0.2% be visible as errorbar on a scale from 300 to 1400?
My suggestion would be to use y-axis to display the median value and y2-axis to display the min/max deviation from the median value, e.g. in percent.

**Code:**

```
### yerrorbars
reset session

$Data <<EOD
#X    Avg       Median  Min         Max
6144  329.355   329.368 329.058899  329.504681
7168  447.697   447.717 447.254499  447.886343
8192  582.577   582.611 581.954116  582.844339
9216  739.178   739.211 738.535311  739.525144
10240  911.311  911.406 910.030310  911.942631
11264  1103.01  1103.08 1101.368124 1103.849248
12288  1312.4   1312.54 1310.437674 1313.122151
EOD

set key left
set ylabel "Median"
set ytics nomirror
set y2label "Deviation from median in %"
set y2tics nomirror

set errorbars large
plot $Data u 1:3 axes x1y1 w p pt 7 lc rgb "red" title "Median",\
    '' u 1:(0):(($4-$3)/$3*100):(($5-$3)/$3*100) axes x1y2 w yerrorbars title "Deviation from median in %"  
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]